# .msi compatibility across Windows versions

Tags: windows-installer

I would like to distribute my winforms application to several different computers, where the OS is everything between XP and Win7.

If I create a .msi installation package (VS2010 - c# 4.0), will it work in windows XP right of the bat?

Is there anything specific I need to change in order to make it work on older computers?

Comment: You will have to think of Processor Architecture- 32x or 64x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MSIs work across all versions of Windows. Having said that, Windows XP doesn't include .NET 4.0 by default, so you'll need to trigger the appropriate framework install if needed.

Comment: Thanks, what about updates to the application? If I release a new .msi , does the OS recognize that and upgrade the previous version?

Comment: That's a feature of the MSI technology, yes. You need to make sure that the product code value in your MSI project is not changed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Visual studio 2010, you will be fine. Just make sure that the project is of type .Net 4.0 or lower, **since .Net 4.5 will not work in XP**, Also make sure that .Net framework is installed on the machine, you can also include the .Net framework with the installation.

See this post for details: [HOW TO: Distribute the .NET Framework with a Visual Studio .NET Deployment Project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work.  However it all depends upon on the prerequisites you have.

For example, it depends on the **.NET FRAMEWORK version** you developed.